# Html Script Pass As String Into Json via to Java

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

```
{ "content" : "<html><body><p>Some text</p></body></html>" }
```

Above mentioned pass html script into json via to java

Comment: can you explain your need properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Jackson** libraries for that.

If you are using spring-boot, then jackson libraries are already included for JSON consumption and production.

For example :

Create a sample class.

```
public class HtmlContent {

  private String content;

  // getters and setters

}
```

Jackson code :

```
public class Example {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
         ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         String json = "{ \"content\" : \"<html><body><p>Some text</p></body></html>\" }";
         HtmlContent htmlContent = objectMapper.readValue(json, HtmlContent.class);
         System.out.println(htmlContent.getHtmlContent());
     }
}
```

Comment: @ chinnappanchinna Plz upvote this as well. :)